# WPF ShowDialog returns null immediately on second call 

Tags: wpf, null, return, showdialog

I think this is a bug in the WPF framework, without going into depths of my program and why I am doing what I am doing, I wrote a simple test application to prove my theory.

Can this issue be confirmed? What are possible workarounds for a series of dialogs to be executed before putting the application into its run loop?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace ShowDialogWindow
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class App : Application
  {
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
       Window testWindow = new Window();
       testWindow.ShowDialog();
       testWindow.Close();
       // THE CODE BELOW WILL NOT SHOW THE NEXT WINDOW
       Window testWindow2 = new Window();
       testWindow2.ShowDialog();
       testWindow2.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

#### Update:

Sure I can change my design to accommodate this behaviour. What I was trying to do was really simple however.

I have derived my `MyApplication` from `Application`. On the `Main()`, I initiate a series of start checks, for example, license information, splash screen, connectivity and configuration checks, ect. When I get my all clear, I call `MyApplicatiom.Run(MyMainForm)`.

This design is based on a normal Windows application which works without a problem.

Thanks a lot for your help, and I will remember that you cannot call `ShowDialog()` before `application.Run()` as it simply innitializes a shutdown. I would have thought however that a shutdown sequence should only be initiated after a `App.Run()` instruction.

Please correct me if I am understanding this wrong.

Answer (score 31):

Not a bug. The default `ShutdownMode` of `Application` is `OnLastWindowClosed`, so as soon as the first window is closed your application will start shutting down! Change to `OnExplicitShutdown` and it will work, but you'll have to manage the shutdown.

I think you probably just need to rethink what you're actually trying to achieve. Why would you display two subsequent dialog windows during the startup of your app?

Comment: An explanation for the down-vote would be most appreciated. Is there something I need to improve in this answer?

Answer (score 5):

For anyone that has the same problem, here is how you can get around it:

```
public App()
{
    // Preserve and temporarily switch shutdown mode
    var oldShutdownMode = ShutdownMode;
    ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;

    var dialog = new Window();
    var result = dialog.ShowDialog();
    dialog = new Window();
    result = dialog.ShowDialog(); // This will show!

    // Reset shutdown mode to original value
    ShutdownMode = oldShutdownMode;    
}
```