# WPF MainWindow Override OnStartup

Tags: c#, wpf

I can't get my MainWindow to show without using StartupUri.
OnStartup doesn't trigger.

I removed StartupUri from App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="SCon"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
</Application>
```

added the following in the code behind

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        SCon.MainWindow.Instance.Show();
    }
```

MainWindow is a singleton

```
    private static volatile MainWindow instance = null;
    private static object lockThis = new object();
    public static MainWindow Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (lockThis)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new MainWindow();
                    }
                }
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There has to be something that's specified as a start up window. Do you mean you want 2 windows to show up automatically when your application starts?

Comment: No it's only the MainWindow turned into a singleton. So I try to override OnStartup to create my window but it never triggers OnStartup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idk what you mean or where you stuck at. I would check Build Actions of App.xaml then I would take a look to this site.

http://www.erikojebo.se/Code/Details/202

That guy explains is pretty well :)

Also your question is sort of a duplicate. Check this out: [How to change StartupUri of WPF Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945843/how-to-change-startupuri-of-wpf-application)

Comment: ApplicationDefinition

Comment: Remove base.OnStartup(e);

Comment: Same it never enters OnStartup

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhh your X:Class is not assigned right. Try this x:Class="Namespace.Class"

Comment: OH Thank you. I changed namespace names and never corrected it here. Thanks it's working as it should now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the following line in the XAML file:

```
<Application x:Class="SCon"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Startup="OnStartup">
</Application>
```

That's why it didn't trigger the OnStartup method.